# Can I upload a file with perl?

Tags: perl

I have a script that needs to send logfiles to a web server.

NOTE:  Server side uploading is already done.  This is the client that needs to upload to the server.

On the server side, I have the typical cgi script that accepts any .zip file I send it under the name "file"  (Example input type="file" name="file" )

So my question is:  Is there an easy way to upload a .zip file to a web server via perl?

Something simple would be ideal, like:
upload_file('http://wherever.com/upload.cgi', 'somefile.zip');

Comment: You can upload a file to a server with perl, yes. Have you done any basic research into the problem?

Comment: Have a look at LWP::UserAgent or WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: Thank you!  LWP::UserAgent put me on the right path!

It is so hard to google for this result, when every result is the server-side code.

Comment: The code would be the same, whether it's running on a server or your own computer. You may find the [lwp cookbook](https://metacpan.org/pod/lwpcook) a useful source of "recipes" for web-related transactions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`HTTP::Request::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common) and [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    env_proxy => 1,
);

my $req = POST 'http://someserver.com/upload.cgi',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [ pageAction => 'upload', file => ['myfile.zip'] ];

$ua->request($req);
```

This can also be written as

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    env_proxy => 1,
);

$ua->request('http://someserver.com/upload.cgi',
    Content_Type => 'form-data',
    Content      => [ pageAction => 'upload', file => ['myfile.zip'] ]
);
```

This is because `$ua->post(...)` is the same as `$ua->request(POST ...)` except the special `:name` headers are handled first.